# Can we add HttpModule after deploying the website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a website which is already live in production and now we need to added httpModule to incorporated the Custom URL Redirection logic.

Therefore we developed the RedirectionHttpModule as class library and this module need new Configuration section need to be added in web.config and need the new RedirectionHttpModule registration in the module tag in web.config.

We deployed this dll in bin folder of production and added the configuration setting in web.config.

Now we are getting Error as ConfigurationManager class is not picking up the new section from the web.config.

Can any one help in resolving this issue and also let us know change HttpModule be added in this way.

Comment: Which version of IIS, how have you registered your module?  Look at the registration section here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227673%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Research the error. You're probably missing a configuration section registration in your configuration. If you can't figure it out, share the actual error and your research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the fix , there was typo error in the code in Web.config. However would like to mention that it got confirmed that we can added the HttpModule to the website which is already deployed without redeploying the whole solution.